# How to scale/resize Mesh Outline?

Tags: three.js

In my current project, I need a way to outline a mesh.This color outline will represent the object's current state, relevant for me.
The problem is that it is a custom mesh, loaded using JSONLoader.
I've tried different approaches, following (mainly) these 2 examples: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html and 
THREEx.geometricglow. In both cases, I scale the mesh outline to a bit bigger than the original. My main problem is that scaling equally in all axis will not cover my object the way I intended to.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 var outlineMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, side: THREE.BackSide, transparent: true, opacity:0.5 } );
                    var outlineMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( object.geometry, outlineMaterial2 );
                    outlineMesh2.position.copy(object.position);
                    outlineMesh2.scale.copy(object.scale);              
                    outlineMesh2.scale.multiplyScalar(1.1)
                    scene.add( outlineMesh2 );
```

`

With a simple cube mesh, the outline will be good.
But with my custom mesh, the scale will not fit the shape correctly.
Here is a image demonstrating: http://s13.postimg.org/syujtd75z/print1.png

Also, using Stemkoski approach, the outlining mesh will also show in front of the object, not just outline (as seen in the above picture).

My question is: How should I resize the mesh? For what I know, it might have something to do with face normals.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: to render it behind you have to set `side:THREE.BackSide`. But the problem is with the geometry you use, this outline way will never work. Think more about it, it's just logic. The only way to solve your problem would be to create a shader.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can the same shader be used on diferent meshes and produce good results?

Comment: unfortunately i know nothing about shaders, and unless you do or someone could write one for you, you will have to find another way than outlining.

Comment: Currently, the only solutions I found were: covering the object with a transparent colored layer; make an outline of a standard box, with the width, length and height of the original mesh. The second option isn't much appealing.